# how to show $\|T\|\le 1$

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces

Given that $M$ is a closed linear subspace of $N$ and if $T$ is a natural mapping of $N\to N/M:x\to x+M$, I have shown that $T$ is continuous , but I am not able to show $\|T\|\le 1$
Thank you for help

Comment: Remember the definition of the norm on $N/M$. Then $\lVert Tx\rVert \leqslant \lVert x\rVert$ is immediate.

Comment: could you please do it bit more?

Comment: $\lVert Tx\rVert = \inf\limits_{m\in M} \lVert x - m\rVert$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to elaborate on Daniel Fischer's comment : $N/M$ is the collection of cosets of $M$ in $N$, where we define the norm as :
$$
\|x+M\| := \inf\{\|y\| : y \in x+M \} = \inf\{\|x+m\| : m \in M \}
$$
Since $M$ is a subspace, $0 \in M$, and so the infimum is $\leq \|x+0\| = \|x\|$

Answer (score 1):

$$\|T\|=\sup_{\|x\|=1}\|Tx\|=\sup_{\|x\|=1}\|x+M\|=\sup_{\|x\|=1}\inf_{m\in M}\|x-m\|\leq\sup_{\|x\|=1}\|x\|=1$$
where the second equality is given by the definition of norm on the quotient, and the last step is obtained by considering $m=0\in M$.

Also for Hilbert spaces you have equality when taking $x\perp M$ (can you prove it?), and thus $\|T\|=1$. I'm not sure whether this is also true for general Banach spaces.

Comment: Supposing $M \neq N$ of course. Yes, it holds for general Banach spaces. For every $x \in N$, and $n > 0$, there is an $m_n \in M$ with $\lVert x - m_n\rVert < \lVert x+M\rVert + \frac1n$. If $x \notin M$, that yields $\lVert T\rVert \geqslant \frac{\lVert x+M\rVert}{\lVert x - m_n\rVert} \geqslant \frac{1}{1+1/(n\lVert x+M\rVert)}$.